# How to specify a DLL file's output directory with MSBuild

Tags: .net, build, msbuild

I've got a big solution with many projects in it. So when it builds it copies many libraries to the build's output directory. How can I specify some DLL file's output directory?

For example:

```
./OutputDir/Libraries/[and here we have some DLL files]

./OutputDir/Program.exe.
```

An [XCOPY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY) post-build action helps me to copy all DLL files into another directory. Here it is post-build action:

```
mkdir "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)\Libraries"

xcopy "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)\*.dll" "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)\Libraries"
```

How should I link those DLL files to an executeable?

Comment: Your update is totally another question. Is about Assembly Binding. Here is the bible: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720133.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set output file at project settings or you can overwrite that at build time with `/property:OutputDir=OutputDir\Libraries`.

If you need a copy of a dll you can do it with a post build action.